# at $T \approx 0 \, \text{K}$, will all energy levels within the electronic band structure be occupied up to a certain level?

Tags: electronic-band-theory

I saw this from the script of my teacher that I don't understand what does it mean

> If we cool down a crystal to an absolute temperature of T ≈ 0K, all atoms of the crystal will exist at their ground states and all energy levels within the electronic band structure
>   will be occupied up to a certain level

At the absolute zero, all electron is at its lowest energy level so the higher level is empty so why ***all energy levels within the electronic band structure
will be occupied up to a certain level***. I don't understand what it means. The higher level is empty so why all energy level (including higher level) is occupied at a certain level?

Answer (score 4):

The [Pauli Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle) means that not every electron can be at the very lowest energy level.